# Stubbing multi parameters method with mockito-scala

Tags: scala, testing, stubbing, mockito-scala

I am trying to stub a method with three parameters to return different responses regarding one of those parameters:

```
val mocked = mock[MyService]
mocked.someInitialization returns mock[State]
mocked.complexMethod(*, *, *) answers { (_:State, discriminant:Discriminant, _:Delegate[MyService]) => 
  discriminant match {
    case _:FirstKind => Right(Option.empty[String])
    case SecondKind(value:String) => Right(Some(value))
    case _ => ???
  }
}
```

However, my test fail with the above message:

```
SmartNull returned by this unstubbed method call on a mock:
myService.complexMethod(
    Mock for State, hashCode: 1730688778,
    FirstKind("UnusedValue"),
    my.system.FixturesAndMock$FakeDelegate@2b5f8e61
); (of class scala.util.Either$MockitoMock$854506859)
```

(I don't understand the sentence "*of class scala.util.Either$MockitoMock$854506859*")

Note that:

- stubbing with `mocked.complexMethod(*, *, *) returns Left(Nil)` have the same issue.
- using `any[State], any[Discriminant], any[Delegate[MyService]]` instead of `*, *, *` does not change anything.

I am using `org.mockito.scalatest.IdiomaticMockito` on Scala 2.12.8 on GraalVM. What am I doing wrong; how can I stub a method to return computed answers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it seems that it was caused by the last parameter, `Delegate[MyService]`. I suspect that the runtime type was not a matching type for the stubbing.

At this time I have a method that enforce the type in `Delegate`. My stubbing is used, and it give a cleaner look to my code by allowing partial function:

```
given(mock[MyService]).answering {
  case (_, _:FirstKind, _) =>
    Right(Option.empty[String])

  case (_, SecondKind(value), _) =>
    Right(Some(value))
}
```